# Routing table have BGP route but unable to ping. R5 192.168.5.1 unable to ping to R6 192.168.6.1

Tags: routing

All have the router have 192.168.5.1 and 192.168.6.1 route in routing table. But unable to ping from 192.168.5.1 to 192.168.6.1

```
R5
router bgp 200
 bgp log-neighbor-changes
 network 10.0.15.0 mask 255.255.255.0
 network 192.168.5.0
 neighbor 10.0.15.2 remote-as 100

R1
router bgp 100
 bgp log-neighbor-changes
 neighbor 10.0.15.1 remote-as 200
 neighbor 192.168.3.1 remote-as 100
 neighbor 192.168.3.1 update-source Loopback0
 neighbor 192.168.3.1 next-hop-self

R3
router bgp 100
          bgp log-neighbor-changes
          neighbor test peer-group
 neighbor test remote-as 100
 neighbor test update-source Loopback0
 neighbor test route-reflector-client
 neighbor 192.168.1.1 peer-group test
 neighbor 192.168.2.1 peer-group test
 neighbor 192.168.4.1 peer-group test

R4
router bgp 100
 bgp log-neighbor-changes
 neighbor 192.168.3.1 remote-as 100
 neighbor 192.168.3.1 update-source Loopback0

R2
router bgp 100
 bgp log-neighbor-changes
 neighbor 192.168.3.1 remote-as 100
 neighbor 192.168.3.1 update-source Loopback0
 neighbor 192.168.3.1 next-hop-self
 neighbor 192.168.6.1 remote-as 300
 neighbor 192.168.6.1 ebgp-multihop 255
 neighbor 192.168.6.1 update-source Loopback0
ip route 192.168.6.0 255.255.255.0 10.0.62.2
ip route 192.168.6.0 255.255.255.0 10.0.26.2


router bgp 300
 bgp log-neighbor-changes
 network 192.168.6.0
 neighbor 192.168.2.1 remote-as 100
 neighbor 192.168.2.1 ebgp-multihop 255
 neighbor 192.168.2.1 update-source Loopback0
ip route 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0 10.0.26.1
```

ip route 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0 10.0.62.1

[image]

Comment: Never, ever use images for text. Simply copy the text and paste it into the question and use the Preformatted-text option on it. Please edit your question to add the text.

Comment: Need “show IP route”,  “show IP BGP” , “show IP BGP nei” from each router.  R1 appears to be configured to be a neighbor with its own loopback.  R3 looks like a route reflector but R2 and R4 are not peered with R3.  Is your diagam in sync with the actual configurations?  Make sure to verify the loopback IPs versus labels in your diagram.  In particular R1 and R3 may be reversed.

Comment: Zin, can you provide `show ip route`, `show ip bgp sum`, `show ip bgp neighbors x.x.x.x advertised-routes` & `show ip bgp neighbours x.x.x.x routes` for all devices/neighbours.